# Calculate mail attachment size in iOS

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, filesize, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to calculate the size of a mail created via `MFMailComposeViewController`.
The user selects some titles from a UITableView and my app fetches appropriate PDF files from a server and attaches it to a new mail.

I'm now trying to calculate the attachment size (to show it or do some restrictions or whatever).

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileIDs.count; i++) {
    NSURL *docUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                          @"http://domain.com/getPDF.php?fileID=%@", 
                                          [fileIDs objectAtIndex:i]]];

    NSData *docData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:docUrl];

    [mailController addAttachmentData:docData 
                    mimeType:@"application/pdf" 
                    fileName:@"file.pdf"];

    mailLength = mailLength + [docData length];

    NSLog(@"Mail generation...\n%i of %i (%.2fMB)", 
          i+1, currentRows.count, ((float)(int)mailLength / 1048576));
}
```

I'm getting an output although. But it's **much** too large. The calculated file size is for example *5.14MB* but the actual size is just *1.2MB*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: whats the raw size before you convert it to int, long and divide it? also, whats "mainLength" ?

Comment: `[NSData length]` results a NSInteger. So mailLength is NSInteger. I lost my example from above. So here's a new one: Result of 25 attached files **Raw:** _10388976_, **Calculated:** _9.91MB_, **Actual:** _2.4MB_

Comment: i more ment like, what number does it hold? do you set it to 0 at the start? does your result always give 9.91mb or does it vary?

Comment: The initial value is `mailLength = 0;`. The size depends on which files I choose... But when I choose the same files the size is "static"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it.

Instead of using NSInteger I just had to use a float. It works right now:

```
// header:
float mailLength;

// implementation:
mailLength = mailLength + [docData length];
NSLog(@"Mail generation...\n%i of %i (%.2fMB)", i+1, currentRows.count, (mailLength / 1048576));
```

Comment: good :) yeah, not too sure what you where doing there with the (int)(float) before division. great that it works!